# Сложный запрос в mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с именами, у каждого имени может быть нескользо пунктов, которые находятся во второй таблице, и есть третья таблица которая их связывает, как сделать такой запрос чтоб на выходе получить все именна (каждое выводится только 1 раз) и для каждого имени весь его список пунктов, в одной таблице?

Users:
  Id, 
  Name

Points:
  Id, 
  Name, 
  Id_user

User_point:
  Id, 
  Id_user, 
  Id_point

Comment: Примеры таблиц приведите

Comment: GROUP BY + GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: Пункты как должны быть выведены, в одном столбце через запятую? Или на каждый пункт отдельный столбец?

Comment: Например первая строка выборки: user - одна ячейка, points-вторая ячейка из столбцов со всеми пунктами

Comment: GROUP BY + GROUP_CONCAT() –этот вариант отлично подходит но мне не только имена пунктов нужно сгрупировать но и их ид

Comment: соберите id отдельным group_concat. или собирайте group_concat некую строку содержащую и id и названия в каком нибудь удобном вам формате, который на клиенте будет легко превратить в то, что вам надо, например `group_concat( concat(points.name, '(', points.id, ')') )`, т.е. на выходе имена и около них в скобках id

Answer (score 0):

На выходе вы сможете получить таблицу, в которой в каждой строке будет имя(первая таблица) и пункт(вторая таблица). Соответственно, если у имени несколько пунктов, то будет несколько строк с одинаковым именем и разными пунктами.
Для того чтобы вывести (на экран, например) имя один раз и все пункты к нему, необходимо написать обработчик данного запроса, который и сделает представление, как вам нужно. 
UPD: Нужно понимать, где вы собираетесь выводить это и что получает результат данного запроса. Например, на PHP можно обработать данный массив и вывести результат в формате html. В цикле обрабатываете каждую строку sql-запроса и формируете вывод. 
Например:
 Вводные данные: sql-запрос . 
 Вывод: новый массив в формате ключ:имя, значение: массив пунктов. 
  Создаем новый массив. 
Читаем каждую строку запроса.
 Если есть в новом массиве ключ: имя. То в значение:массив добавляем пункт. 
Если нет ключ: имя, то создаем такой ключ и в значение добавляем пустой массив.
 В этот массив вставляем пункт.

Comment: Как можно сделать такой обработчик? Как из массива можно удалить одинаковые элементы чтоб остался только один

Comment: `Как из массива можно удалить одинаковые элементы чтоб остался только один` - array_unique()